# Architecture for DatabaseConnection in a REST application

Tags: database, rest, architecture, database-connection

my question seems very simple, but there are some subquestions which requires deeper inspection.
My Question:
**What's the best practice/architecture for handle the database connection?**

My found options:

1. For each rest ful service with database(DB) requests create a new
   connection to the DB and close this again after the queries.
2. Create a connection outside the REST Service and use this for each
       query.

Option 1.:
One negativ point of this are the costs for etablish and close the connection for each request.

Option 2.:
Don't know whether it's work. I've researched for the Web Service Lifecycle for checking how this could be work, but don't know whether the instances will stay alive after the finish of the Web Service. Also don't know whether it's a good practice because there could be events which destroy the connection. A last issue is I think the requests could be block each other (So it destroys the concept of threads).

Hope you could help me a little bit with this architecture.

Greets,

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create one per query / transaction, it is much easier to manage "closing" the connections.

I can see why common sense dictates that you should open one and use it throughout, but you will run into problems with dropped connections and multithreading. So your next step will be to open a pool, say of 50, connections and keep them all open, doling them out to different processes.

If you open a connection when you need it and dispose of it when you've finished, that will not actually close the connection, it'll just return it to the connection pool to be used again.

Comment: Thanks the main concept you name is "Connection Pool/ing" which helped me a lot. I've found some frameworks/services which offers such **Connection Pool**. In my case Apache Tomcat offers also such a service.